# jQuery-File-Upload Change dir for upload and list of image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

i'm trying to change the upload path and the image list path in jQuery file upload....
I'm using Jquery file upload via angularJS....and that is what i have till now....

this is the URL set in the app.js

```
var url =  'server/php/index.php?myfolder=/content/media/gallery/1/';
```

this is the callback on jqueryFileUpload.js

```
submit: function (e, data) {
 var folder = '/content/media/gallery/1/';
    data.formData = {myfolder: folder}; 
 },
```

and this is the PHP

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$myFolder = $_REQUEST['myfolder'];
$uploadFolder = '../../..'. $myFolder;
$uploadUrl = 'myUrl/mainfolder'. $myFolder;
$options = array(
    'upload_dir' => $uploadFolder,
    'upload_url' => $uploadUrl
);


$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

i had try also to change the path inside UploadHandler.php but it's still uploading file in the file folder
someone have some ideas???

Thank you...

Comment: Try to use full path instead of relative path

Comment: Nothing change....still uploading on the /file folder...